# Why does easeljs stage.getBounds() return null?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

In this example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

function drawRectangle(){
 var rect = new createjs.Shape();
 rect.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
 stage.addChild(rect);
}

function drawShapes(){
  drawRectangle();
 stage.update();
}

drawShapes();
// Why does this call log null?
console.log(stage.getBounds());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EaselJS/0.8.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
```

`stage.getBounds();` is returning null. Why does it return null? According to the [docs](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#method_getBounds), it's supposed to return a rectangle object representing the dimensions of the bounding box of the stage.

If this usage is incorrect, what is the correct usage to get the dimensions of the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the **stage** object can't calculate their own bounds.

In the same `getBounds()` [documentation](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#method_getBounds) it appears the following:

> Not all display objects can calculate their own bounds (ex. Shape). For these objects, you can use [setBounds](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_setBounds) so that they are included when calculating Container bounds.

If it's the case, as the documentation says, you can use the `setBounds()` method ([documentation](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_setBounds)) to set manually the bounds of the object:

```
setBounds(x,y,width,height)
```

In the case of your code:

```
stage.setBounds(0,0,600,150); // (0,0), at the same size of the canvas
```

Comment: Stage should return bounds if a) it has bounds set on it like in this example; or b) It has child contents that can calculate bounds (Bitmaps, Sprites, Text). It is the same as any container. Graphics can not calculate bounds, which is why your demo doesn't return stage bounds.